# Getting list of services on a remote PC

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am using [ServiceController.GetServices()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s21fd6th%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) succcessfully on a local machine to get a list of services. I should be able to do the same for another PC with the supplied `machineName` parameter.

The two PCs are on the same LAN, same network mask, same workgroup. I am the local admin on both with an identical password. My application is running with elevated permissions and yet I get `InvalidOperationException` with `Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'XXX'. This operation might require other privileges.`

What else do I need to do to make this work? I have seen some references about "impersonation" in order for this to work but I am not sure what is to impersonate if users are matched on two PCs. I can access network shares w/o having to enter any credentials.

I would hate to have to resort to WMI for solution as there is a clean C# way for this.

Comment: If you open `Services.msc` on your local machine, right click "Services (Local)", choose "Connect to another computer", enter the remote machine name and press "OK", what result do you get? If it's still an error, then it's a more general error you need to solve and the C# code is probably fine.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have tried that before and I can't connect from there either. Still, I can't see what could be the problem.

Comment: As you are not on a domain then I would say that username@PC1 or PC1\username is different to username@PC2, in other words if possible then specify the username as computerName\username

Comment: You probably don't have sufficient permissions on the remote computer.